# Ctrl + z not working on visual studio code and not working by using no-screen keyboard, win-10

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, ctrl

Control  + z is not working in visual studio code.
I have opened the VS code keyboard shortcut detector, ctrl can get detected, z can get detected, z+ ctrl can get detected, ctrl+ z failed. It seems after I press ctrl, z will get blocked. However, for others key combinations, they are all good in VS code.
I even tried to use on-screen keyboard to input ctrl-z to VS code, still not detecting.

However, I have tried ctrl-z in onenote, it is good.

What I have tried:
I have tried changing language to reset keyboard, not working
I have tried clean boot of win 10, not working
I have tried creating a new windows user, it works! But, I don't want to use another account and migrate all my data and programs, besides, I don't want to lose my current account email.

Comment: Adding more information: VS code version is 1.51.1  .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
You can reset your Keybinds in Visual Studio.

**READ FIRST**

**1)**
go to
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard. Or by type "keybindings"
in the Search.

**2)**
Then on the right you can just reset" all of your keybinds (easy).
Or assign them again(if you assinte different keybinds before).

- By typing "undo" on the right in the first text box. then you see "
  Edit.Undo. Then just press Ctrl + c -> assign.

**3)**
**Restard your Visual Studio and be happy that your handicap is gon.**

---

If it is not fixt, then try it agen.

Else i dont know.

If you have problems with other keys do the same by searching your keybind on
internet *"What is the name of control + c" = "Undo"*. Or just reset your ALL of your keybinds.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue as well. For me it was that I have a German keyboard layout (z and y changed position in comparison to English layout). While typing in the editor z and y were in the correct position but for whatever reason they were flipped again when hitting ctrl in advance. So I worked around it by changing the commands. Typing ctrl+z resulted in ctrl+y and vice versa.

Edit: You can change the keyboard shortcuts in Settings>Keyboard Shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

Go to File > Preferences > Settings search Keyboard.

On application > Keyboard tab, you have a selector as you can see in this screenshot

Selector in Settings > application > keyboard
[image]

I switched the value of this selector from code(default) to keycode.

Now it works with my keyboard in French layout.

Answer (score 0):

Well i hade the same issue, it happened that ctrl+z shortcut was replaced by setting interactiveEditor.undo, i just restored ctrl+z for default:undo action and it all worked!

[Settings->Keyboard Shortcuts->Search CTRL+Z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Uii.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

for recovering the files and folders
simply go to windows recyclebin and restore your folders and files

for the shortcommand
on vs code click on settings -> keyboard shortcuts -> search for undo
Here you can see the shortcut command for undoing as well as redoing.
Thanks.